# Torus and Elliptic curves

Tags: complex-analysis, elliptic-curves, elliptic-functions

In a conference on elliptic curves (an introduction to the subject), the speaker said that an elliptic curve (I.e. an equation of the form $y^2=x^3+ax+b $ where the RHS has distinct roots) is, in the complex space, a torus/Riemann surface of genus 1.

What is meant by that? Are we talking about a 2-dimensional manifold the 4D space?

Comment: One can also use Riemann-Roch for see that the Abel-Jacobi map is an isomorphism.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If $\Lambda = \mathbb{Z}+\tau \mathbb{Z}, \tau \not\in \mathbb{R}$ is a lattice then $\mathbb{C}/\Lambda$ is a complex torus. We have the Weierstrass function of the lattice $$\wp(z) = \frac{1}{z^2}+\sum_{\lambda \in \Lambda^*} \frac{1}{(z-\lambda)^2} -\frac{1}{\lambda^2}$$
which is meromorphic and $\Lambda$ periodic, with a double pole on $\mathbb{C}/\Lambda$. From the Laurent expansion $\wp(z) = z^{-2}+0z^0+g_2 z^2+ g_3 z^4+\mathcal{O}(z^6)$ and because an entire doubly periodic function is constant, we find a non-linear relation :
$$\wp'(z)^2 = 4 \wp(z)^3- g_2 \wp(z)-g_3$$
In other words, we have found an isomorphism (of Riemann surface **and** group)
$$\varphi : \mathbb{C}/\Lambda \to E, \qquad \varphi(z) = (\wp(z),\wp'(z))$$
where $E$ is the complex elliptic curve $$E = \{ (x,y) \in \mathbb{C}^2, y^2 = 4x^3-g_2 x-g_3\}$$
Finally, applying change of variables to $x,y $ we find any complex elliptic curve is isomorphic to such a complex torus by the mean of its Weierstrass function.

Comment: Your answer is quite advanced for me but it givese the idea. Thank you!

Comment: @Friedrich For me the complex analysis point of view is easier than the algebraic geometry's one. There are different approaches. Often, [books on elliptic curves](http://www.jmilne.org/math/CourseNotes/AV.pdf) start by showing the abstract statement that any Riemann surface of genus $1$ is a complex torus, by looking at the invariant differential and the function fields.

Comment: It's important to be careful with the point at infinity in $E$ though.

Comment: If an entire doubly periodic function is constant, how come $\wp(z)$ isn't constant? Edit: nvm, only $\wp(z)-\frac{1}{z^2}$ is periodic.

Comment: @programjames $\wp(z)$ is periodic but not entire, it has some double pole at each lattice point

Comment: As Mr. Chip hints at, one has to be careful with the equivalence class $[0]\in \mathbb{C}/\Lambda$. That is, the function $\varphi$ is not defined at $[0]$ and only gives an isomorphism (of Riemann surfaces) between the punctured torus and $E$. However, $\varphi$ induces and isomorphism between the complex torus and the projective closure of $E$ (given by $\varphi([z])=[\wp(z):\wp'(z):1]$ if $[z]\neq 0$ and $\varphi([0])=[0:1:0]$ else). Or am I missing something?